# As3 Finding&loading all possible id's?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, list, actionscript

I'm not much of an ActionScripter or Flash developer and I don't really know the term I am looking for. Example:

```
bla.php?id=0
```

What I am trying to do is load All possible Id's of a url (in xml format) to a List

```
var Loader:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://website.com/bla.php?id=");
```

I can load a single id by just doing

```
var Loader:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://website.com/bla.php?id=14484");
```

But this isn't what I want to do. How would I got about requesting/finding all possible ids and then display said id's or a certain part of each id to the list?

I don't really know how to explain it but I hope this helps and I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

As id can be theoretically nearly everything or at least a hughe amount of values, the only way imho would be, that the author of bla.php tells you, what are possible values for id. 
If this is a fixed list of values (unlikely), you can use this list then or read it from the server (if the list is provided there). 
If id refers to an identifier of database entries (probably the case), an additional script may be required that reads all ids from the db and returns it to your script (via xml or otherwise).

Comment: Yeah, it's not really an ActionScript question - it can't be solved by ActionScript, it needs to be solved by the PHP-side.